# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in android

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

I make a project and test it.

I test in my device Galaxy S7(Mashmellow), it works fine, but another device SHV-205(Kitkat), it occurs error like this.

```
09-23 15:24:45.981 10438-10438/com.thewell.thewell_dev.companylink E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.thewell.thewell_dev.companylink, PID: 10438
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.thewell.thewell_dev.companylink/com.thewell.thewell_dev.fourslink.Activity.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.thewell.thewell_dev.fourslink.Activity.SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.thewell.thewell_dev.companylink-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.thewell.thewell_dev.companylink-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

I use android studio.
I test it and upload to Google play store, but it works fine.

I don't know why this problem occurs this error.

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this Error already, and found the solution myself,

If you are placed you splashscreen activity in your Activity package, please move it to outer package(Main package)

as shown in below Image..!

[image: wrong]
[image: Correct]